# How to sort a TObjectList by two (or more) class members?

Tags: delphi, tobjectlist

Assume a very simple object

```
TPerson = class
private 
    name : String;
    DateOfBirth: TDatetime;
end;
.
.
aList : TObjectList<TPerson>;
.
.
```

let's say aList is populated like this:

| name | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 01/01/2023 |
| Alice | 01/02/2023 |
| Adam | 01/01/2022 |

how to sort aList by name and birthdate ?

I tried

```
  aList.sort(TComparer<TPerson>.Construct(
      function (const L, R: TPerson): integer
      begin
         if L.name=R.name then
            Result:=0
         else if L.name< R.name then
            Result:=1
         else
            Result:=-1;
      end));
```

this works by name but within the same name i want to sort by DateOfBirth too

i want my object sorted this way:

| name | DateOfBirth |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 01/01/2022 |
| Adam | 01/01/2023 |
| Alice | 01/02/2023 |

how can i do it?

btw i'm using Delphi XE10

Comment: There is no such version "Delphi XE10"! Last XE version was Delphi XE8, after that the "XE" was dropped from the version names, and city names have been added at the end.

Comment: well thank you, just as well you clarified it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two names compare the same, you need to then compare their birthdays and return that result, eg:

```
aList.sort(TComparer<TPerson>.Construct(
      function (const L, R: TPerson): integer
      begin
         if L.name = R.name then
         begin
            if L.DateOfBirth = R.DateOfBirth then
               Result := 0
            else if L.DateOfBirth < R.DateOfBirth then
               Result := 1
            else
               Result := -1;
         end
         else if L.name < R.name then
            Result := 1
         else
            Result := -1;
      end));
```

Alternatively, there are RTL functions available for comparing strings and dates, eg:

```
aList.sort(TComparer<TPerson>.Construct(
      function (const L, R: TPerson): integer
      begin
         Result := CompareStr(L.name, R.name);
         if Result = 0 then 
            Result := CompareDate(L.DateOfBirth, R.DateOfBirth);
         Result := -Result;
      end));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the case when Name property match.

```
AList.Sort(TComparer<TPerson>.Construct(
  function (const L, R: TPerson): Integer
  begin
     if L.Name = R.Name then
     begin
       if L.DateOfBirth = R.DateOfBirth then Exit(0);
       if L.DateOfBirth < R.DateOfBirth then Exit(1);
       Exit(-1);
     end;
     if L.Name < R.Name then Exit(1);
     Result := -1;
  end));
```